# Difficulty in understanding $F[x]$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

This is the explanation why $V$ is an $F[x]$-module:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The book said "The linear map $T$ will enable us to make $V$ into an $F[x]$-module " why this happened?

Also, I did not understand the statement " $\circ$ denotes composition of functions (which make sense because the domain and codomain of $T$ are the same )", what is the relation between composition of functions, and domain & codomain? could anyone tell me please?

The book said that "The definition of the $F[x]$ action on $V$ is consistent with the given action of the field $F$ on the vector space $V$", but I can not see how, could anyone explain this for me please?

Could anyone explain the page for me in a clearer and simpler way please?

thanks!!

Comment: I think you should be more specific than "I don't understand this entire page. Someone explain it to me." Surely you get *many parts* of it, and can see the parts you don't get. If you don't, I'm skeptical about how much you can be helped...

Comment: Ok I do not get the idea of why $F[x]$ is a module ?@rschwieb

Comment: @rschwieb Also, I did not understand the statement " $\circ$ denotes composition of functions (which make sense because the domain and codomain of $T$ are the same )", what is the relation between composition of functions, and domain & codomain? could anyone tell me please?

Comment: Also @rschwieb The book said "The linear map $T$ will enable us to make $V$ into an $F[x]$-module " why  this happened?

Comment: Expanded my answer based on those questions. Might be too late but I wanted to give my version for completeness of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll illustrate with an example, and perhaps it helps.

Take $F = \Bbb R$, so $R$ is the ring of polynomials with real coefficients, and let $V = \Bbb R^2$, so that our vector space is the plane with regular vector addition and scalar multiplication. Finally, let $T$ be rotation anti-clockwise by $90^\circ$, represented in the standard basis, as you probably know, by the matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ which I shall also call $T$, by abuse of notation.

$V$ is a module over $\Bbb R$ via the regular scalar multiplication. Now we make $V$ into an $\Bbb R[x]$ module by defining the following module multiplication:
$$
p\cdot v = p(T)v
$$
where the right side is regular matrix multiplication. An example of this multiplicaion might make things even clearer: If $p(x) = x^2 + x + 1$, and $v = (1, 1)^t$, then we have
$$
p\cdot v = (T^2 + T + 1)v = T^2v + Tv + v\\
= \begin{pmatrix}-1\\-1\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}\\
= \begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: The book said "The linear map $T$ will enable us to make $V$ into an $F[x]$-module " why and how this happened?

Comment: Also, I did not understand the statement " $\circ$ denotes composition of functions (which make sense because the domain and codomain of $T$ are the same )", what is the relation between composition of functions, and domain & codomain? could anyone tell me please?

Comment: Sorry, you already explained how :)

Comment: @Intuition If you want to compose two functions $f$ and $g$ to make a new function $f\circ g$, then you have to make sure that whatever you get out of $g$ (i.e. the codomain of $g$) is something you can apply $f$ to (i.e. is in the domain of $f$). In this case, what you get out of $T$ (which is a vector in $V$) is something that it makes sense to apply $T$ to. That means you can safely compose $T$ with $T$.

Comment: Is there is a relation between the above prove and the proof that $R[x_{1} , x_{2}, \dots , x_{n}]$ is an $R$- module?

Comment: @Intuition That it is a module over what ring? $R$? Then no, that module structure is induced by the inclusion $R\subseteq R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and the multiplication in the ring $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. In that the proof relies on no theory, but just verifies the axioms directly, they are similar, but not much else.

Answer (score 0):

> Ok I do not get the idea of why $F[x]$ is a module ?

The contents of the page you included explain *why $V$ is an $F[x]$-module.* It does so by defining an action $F[x]\times V\to V$.

$F[x]$ is a module over $F[x]$, but that does not seem like the main point of this page.

> what is the relation between composition of functions, and domain & codomain?

If $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$, then you can compose them to become $g\circ f:A\to C$ *because* the codomain of $f$ matches the domain of $g$. If you don't have this condition, the composition doesn't make sense. If you want to compose a map with itself, well then you'd better have $T:V\to V$ like we have here so that things line up.

> "The linear map $T$ will enable us to make $V$ into an $F[x]$-module " why this happened?

$V$ was already a vector space, so we knew how $F$ was acting on $V$. To make $x$ act on $V$, we're selecting a linear transformation $T$ to tell us what $x$ does to $V$.

After you decide what $x$ does to $V$, then you have no choice about what $x^n$ does to $V$, because it must be the same thing as repeatedly applying $T$ $n$ times. By linearity, this completely determines what $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ix^i$ does to $V$.